# Parsing comma-separated values containing quoted commas and newlines

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, csv

I have string with some special characters. 
The aim is to retrieve String[] of each line (, separated)
You have special character “ where you can have /n and ,

```
For example Main String
Alpha,Beta,Gama,"23-5-2013,TOM",TOTO,"Julie, KameL
Titi",God," timmy, tomy,tony,
tini".
```

You can see that there are you /n in "".

Can any Help me to Parse this.

Thanks

__ More Explanation

with the Main Sting I need to separate these

```
Here Alpha
Beta
Gama
23-5-2013,TOM
TOTO
Julie,KameL,Titi
God
timmy, tomy,tony,tini
```

Problem is : for Julie,KameL,Titi there is line break /n or 
 in between KameL and Titi
similar problem for timmy, tomy,tony,tini there is line break /n or 
 in between tony and tini.

---

new this text is in file (compulsory line by line reading)

```
Alpha,Beta Charli,Delta,Delta Echo ,Frank George,Henry
1234-5,"Ida, John
 ", 25/11/1964, 15/12/1964,"40,000,000.00",0.0975,2,"King, Lincoln 
 ",Mary / New York,123456
12543-01,"Ocean, Peter
```

output i want to remove this "

```
Alpha
Beta Charli
Delta
Delta Echo
Frank George
Henry
1234-5
Ida
John
"
25/11/1964
15/12/1964
40,000,000.00
0.0975
2
King
Lincoln
"
Mary / New York
123456
12543-01
Ocean
Peter
```

Comment: So "Ida" and "John" should appear on two different lines? I thought you need: "1234-5" on one line. Then "Ida, John" on the second line and "25/11/1964" on the third (without the quotes) because the quotes embrace Ida and John into one single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String source = "Alpha,Beta,Gama,\"23-5-2013,TOM\",TOTO,\"Julie, KameL\n"
              + "Titi\",God,\" timmy, tomy,tony,\n"
              + "tini\".";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([^\"][^,]*)|\"([^\"]*)\"),?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);

while(m.find())
{
    if(m.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println( m.group(2).replace("\n", "") );
    else if(m.group(3) != null)
        System.out.println( m.group(3).replace("\n", "") );
}
```

If it matches a string without quotes, the result is returned in group 2.
Strings with quotes are returned in group 3. Hence i needed a distinction in the while-block.
You might find a prettier way.

**Output:**
Alpha
Beta
Gama
23-5-2013,TOM
TOTO
Julie, KameLTiti
God
 timmy, tomy,tony,tini
.

Comment: ya this works. Can you explain me `("(([^\"][^,]*)|\"([^\"]*)\"),?")`

Comment: :This work fine for the given input. Basically This input is in a file and i have to read the file line by line(compulsory to read line by line). I read the file line by line using BufferReader and treat this line as a source in your code. Because of line by reading i could not remove " .
I have attached the input and output in Edit Section

Comment: note: `[^\"]` could match a comma. if any of the entries are empty string, then this regexp will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing CSV is a whole lot harder than one would imagine at first sight, and that's why your best option is to use a well-designed and tested library to do that work for you.  Two libraries are [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and [supercsv](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/index.html), and many others.  Have a look at both and use the one that's the best fit to your requirements and style.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex [tested on a Java parser](http://fiddle.re/dwz06) which requires no extra processing to reassemble the data parts. The first matching group will match a quote, then carry that to the end of the match so that you're assured to capture the entire value between **but not including the quotes**. I also don't capture the commas unless they were embedded a quote delimited substring.

`(?:^|,\s{0,})(["]?)\s{0,}((?:.|\n|\r)*?)\1(?=[,]\s{0,}|$)`

## Example

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'Alpha,Beta,Gama,"23-5-2013,TOM",TOTO,"Julie, KameL\n
Titi",God,"timmy, \n
tomy,tony,tini"'
$Regex = '(?:^|,\s{0,})(["]?)\s{0,}((?:.|\n|\r)*?)\1(?=[,]\s{0,}|$)'

Write-Host start with 
write-host $String
Write-Host
Write-Host found
([regex]"(?i)(?m)$Regex").matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "key at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'`t= value at $($_.Groups[2].Index) = '$($_.Groups[2].Value)'"
    } # next match
```

## Yields

```
start with
Alpha,Beta,Gama,"23-5-2013,TOM",TOTO,"Julie, KameL\n
Titi",God,"timmy, \n
tomy,tony,tini"

found
key at 0 = ''   = value at 0 = 'Alpha'
key at 6 = ''   = value at 6 = 'Beta'
key at 11 = ''  = value at 11 = 'Gama'
key at 16 = '"' = value at 17 = '23-5-2013,TOM'
key at 32 = ''  = value at 32 = 'TOTO'
key at 37 = '"' = value at 38 = 'Julie, KameL\n
Titi'
key at 60 = ''  = value at 60 = 'God'
key at 64 = '"' = value at 65 = 'timmy, \n
tomy,tony,tini'
```

## Summary

[image]

- `(?:` start non capture group
- `^` require start of string
- `|` or
- `,\s{0,}` a comma followed by any number of white space
- `)` close the non capture group
- `(` start capture group 1
- `["]?` consume a quote if it exists, I like doing it this way incase you want to include other characters then a quote
- `)` close capture group 1
- `\s{0,}` consume any spaces if they exist, this means you don't need to trim the value later
- `(` start capture group 2
- `(?:.|\n|\r)*?` capture all characters including a new line, non greedy
- `)` close capture group 2
- `\1` if there was a quote it would be stored in group 1, so if there was one then require it here
- `(?=` start zero assertion look ahead
- `[,]\s{0,}` must have a comma followed by optional whitespace
- `|` or
- `$` end of the string
- `)` close the zero assertion look ahead

Comment: How did you generate that diagram?

Comment: there are a few mistakes in this: the `\s{0,}` in your lookahead is meaningless, you are consuming leading spaces inside a quoted string, and other inconsistent handling of whitespaces. but the worst problem is no consideration of escaped backslashes... which is why most developers would advise using a csv parser instead of a regex.

Comment: I'm not going to debate the merrits of using Regex for parsing CSV. Requesters generally has their reasons for using Regex over other more capable parsing solutions. I see you also posted a Regex based solution, so your feeling here is moot. The `{0,}` construct says zero or more times and is replicated by the `*`. Including support for escaped backslashes was not required by OP.

Comment: I am aware of what the `{0,}` construct means, but my point was that including optional trailing space for a lookahead does nothing in particular, so it was extraneous. The comment about moot feelings seems a little off topic. For what it's worth, I posted what I consider a "decent" regex, just to save people searching for one, but I still agree with [the answer by fgv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533149/7098259). I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806378/7098259) for a decent Java-compatible regex for parsing CSV.

It recognizes:

- Newlines (after values or inside quoted values)
- Quoted values containing escaped double-quotes like `""this""`

In short, you will use this pattern: `(?:,|\n|^)("(?:(?:"")*[^"]*)*"|[^",\n]*|(?:\n|$))`

Then collect each Matcher `group(1)` in a `find()` loop.

---

**Note:** Although I have posted this answer here about a "decent" regex I discovered, just to save people searching for one, it is by no means robust. I still agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533149/7098259) by user "fgv": a CSV Parser is preferrable.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work correctly with escaped double-double qouotes, such as strings like `"""alpha""", "beta,""charlie"",delta"`. See also [this link](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy3bxxyr) and click the Java button.

Comment: @RoYoMi for the example you posted, it fails because there is a space between `,` and `"beta`. I'm not sure if that should be considered a valid input or not. Sure, it would be nice to make the regex more robust, but if you are using a regex then you had better have well-formed input.