# Split on comma not enclosed by quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string using a regular expression (re.split), but it's been a while since I've been using regular expressions.

The string looks like:

```
string = '"first, element", second element, third element, "fourth, element", fifth element'
```

I would like to split the string on each comma unless a substring is enclose by quotes.

The output should look like this:

```
output = ['"first, element"', 'second element', 'third element', '"fourth, element"', 'fifth element']
```

Comment: Any attempts so far? Also, [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21261314/1578604). IMO, it's easier to use match though.

Comment: Regex is the wrong way to approach this problem. Quoted strings can have escape characters, you should use `shlex.split` instead.

Comment: Or parse it as csv using the csv module - because that's what it really is.

Comment: See also [How do I split a line by commas but ignore commas within quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7682561), [How do I split a comma delimited string in python except for the commas that are within quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4982531), [How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2785755), [and more](https://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=python+split+commas+except+inside+quotes&nfpr=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '"first, element", second element, third element, "fourth, element", fifth element'
>>> m = re.split(r', (?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|, (?=[^",]+(?:,|$))', string)
>>> m
['"first, element"', 'second element', 'third element, "fourth, element"', 'fifth element']
```

<sub>Regex stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25471762/3297613) :-)</sub>

Comment: I have marked this as the solution as it is technically the answer to my question although I agree that the csv module is the way to go here

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module instead of reinventing it.

Comment: I was trying to create an example using `csv.reader`, but no luck so far. It looks like it can't cope with some items being wrapped in quotes, and some not.

Comment: thanks @Bjorn, I was able to parse the line using the csv module

Comment: @Bjorn - perhaps something else is going wrong, because the `csv` module most certainly can parse lines where some fields have the delimiter contained within quotes, whereas other lines have no quotes whatsoever.

Comment: didn't work for combination of commas, colon and escaping: 'categoryFilter: ["5"],priceRanges: "[{\\"min\\":0,\\"max\\":667}]"'