# Split CSV with a regex

Tags: regex, csv, split

I would like to have a CSV parser. However, I would like to have the following: the regex must check, that the CSV ends with a comma `,` (otherwise the regex must not consider the CSV as valid)! If CSV is OK, then I will extract the text between `,`.

Example:

```
hello,world,end, //OK. CSV ends with ",". There are 3 matches: 'hello' 'world' 'end'

aa,bb,cc //NOT ok. CSV doesn't end with ",". No matches.
```

I have a question to [the regex suggested by @Denomales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362695/2604243). If the CSV contains quoted parts, there is always a match that contains only a quotation mark. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, where I modified [your regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30416711/3832970).

Comment: You should have included your regex here, you would not have a down vote.

Comment: basic regex `(?=.*,$)([^,]+)(?:,)`

Comment: You are not doing anything relative to CSV, why is it in the question topic? `Does string end with a comma` should be the topic. For that its `,$`. What does CSV have to do with it ??

Comment: What language do you use? Could you add pertinent examples (in particular with quotes)?

Comment: You can _split_ csv, but if the values can be quoted it throws everything off.

Comment: The simplest way to parse dbl quoted csv: `"` is escape char `(?:^|,)\s*("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^,]*?)\s*(?=,|$)` or '\' is escape `(?:^|,)\s*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,]*?)\s*(?=,|$)`. There are many more options that can be done. But _split_ on delimiter is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking about the [regex suggested by @Denomales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147076/3832970), there can be something we can do about it.

To make sure we only match a string with a comma at the end, you can add a positive look-ahead at the beginning of the pattern (marked with `^` below):

```
(?=.*,$)(?:^|,)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)
^^^^^^^^       |
```

And if you do not want to capture the entry-delimiting mark (the quotes), you can just remove the `(?=[^"]|(")?)` look-ahead (marked with `|` above).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH0yZ0/4)

**UPDATE**

I see you have posted 2 answers to the above mentioned thread. Your regex is almost all you need, just add the look-ahead and a means to skip escaped entities:

```
(?=.*,$)(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|([^,]*))(?:[,])
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tH0yZ0/3)

Comment: Fails at `hello,"world",end`, `hello,"worl\"d",end,` and `hello,worl"d,end,`

Comment: @Havenard: I think it should not match `hello,"world",end`. Did you read the question? The regex is taken from the [above mentioned SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30362695/2604243) and adjusted according to the requirements.

Comment: @Havenard: Again, please read the question, OP does not mention the kind of CSV there is to parse, OP is interested in the regex from a specific SO post.

Comment: @Havenard: It appears that OP already solved the issues you mention above, just forgot to post those efforts here. I updated the regex and now it matches the strings you tested. Please check Demo 2.

Comment: `(?=[^"]|"?)` is an always true assertion.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Good catch :) Updated.

Comment: My mistake, in Demonales pattern it is: `(?=[^"]|(")?)` the goal was to define the capture group 1 (needed for the following conditional test).

Comment: Your first regex has a hole in it. Its possible to drop malformed field data. `[^"]*|[^,"]*` never lets malformed field with dbl quotes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx @stribizhev, it works perfect.

If i understand correct, the comma could also be escaped:
`(?=.*,$)(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|((?:\\.|[^,])*))(?:[,])`

Just for the completeness:-)