# CSV parser in Clojure needs to avoid commas in quotes

Tags: regex, csv, clojure

UPDATE: Pass this:

```
#",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

to `clojure.string/split` to parse CSV.

UPDATE: I need a regex that matches all commas that are not in quotes, in a form that can be used by `clojure.string/split`.

I have written a CSV parse function in Clojure:

```
(defn parse-csv [data schema]
  (let [split-data (clojure.string/split data #",")]
    (loop [rm-data split-data
           rm-keys (:keys schema)
           rm-trans (:trans schema)
           final {}]
      (if (empty? rm-keys)
           final
          (recur (rest rm-data)
                 (rest rm-keys)
                 (rest rm-trans)
                 (into final
                   {(first rm-keys)
                   ((first rm-trans) (first rm-data))}))))))
```

`schema` is simply a hash map consisting of a list of keywords and a list of functions (which are applied to their respective values). This is used to define how the output hash map will look.
Here's an example:

```
(def schema {:keys [:foo :bar :baz] :trans [identity read-string identity]})
(parse-csv "Hello,42,world" schema) ;; returns {:foo "Hello", :bar 42, :baz "world"}
```

However, if we do this:

```
(def schema {:keys [:foo :bar :baz] :trans [identity identity identity]})
(parse-csv "Hello,\"Newell, Gabe\",world" schema) ;; returns {:foo "Hello" :bar "\"Newell" :baz "Gabe\""}
```

Things get messed up, and the word "world" is ignored. The result *should* look like:

```
{:foo "Hello" :bar "\"Newell, Gabe\"" :baz "world"}
```

The above data, in a file, would actually look like `Hello,"Newell, Gabe",world`, so we need to avoid triggering the `split` function when it comes across the comma in `"Newell, Gabe"`.

We need a function that will split a string by a certain character *unless* the certain character is in quotes.

Comment: In order to allow commas inside quoted strings, you would need to first split out strings, then make fields out of what is left. Or use a real parser.

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/data.csv reads this correct with default options: `(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]) (csv/read-csv "Hello,\"Newell, Gabe\",world") ; => (["Hello" "Newell, Gabe" "world"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow seperators inside fields (here `,`), those fields need to be quoted.

What you are doing here with `\"` is **escaping** the quotes (unix style, quotes can also be escaped with another quote).

So, for allowing the `,` inside the field :

```
"Hello,"Newell, Gabe",world"
```

Those outer quotes should not be part of the csv of course.

**Udate** after edit of the question:

> The above data, in a file, would actually look like Hello,"Newell,
>   Gabe",world, so we need to avoid triggering the split function when it
>   comes across the comma in "Newell, Gabe".

```
Hello,"Newell, Gabe",world
```

This is perfectly valid csv, but if this is processed with a pure split function on the `,` you are in trouble.

One option might be to use another seperator like `|` or `;` for example.

**Update 2**:

> so I need a new function that splits the CSV string into fields unless
>   the comma is in quotes (I can't change the dataset). How would I go
>   about implementing this?

For each line, you would need to scan over every character, somewhat like this in pseudo code (I don't know Clojure, so I can't provide you some code, but I work a lot with large csv-files):

```
bool InsideQuotes = false;
loop through chars
  if `,` and InsideQuotes == false -> new field
  if `"` -> InsideQuotes = !InsideQuotes
```

This way quotes inside a quoted field can be escaped with another quote. For example:

```
Hello,"17"" monitor, Samsung",world
```

**Update**:

For some `Regex` on csv see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757107/5708620) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv).

Comment: The data, in a file, would actually look like `Hello,"Newell, Gabe",world`, so we need to avoid triggering the `split` function when it comes across the comma in `"Newell, Gabe"`.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: Ok, your comment (and question) has changed - see update in answer.

Comment: After updated answer: I am using my CSV "reader thingy" on someone else's (multi-megabyte) dataset, so I need a new function that splits the CSV string into fields *unless* the comma is in quotes (I can't change the dataset). How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Ooh, sorry - didn't want to offend you! I thought the csv parser was part of Clojure.. Title says: "Clojure CSV parser". I'll update the answer some more.