# Comma delimited string to array using regular expressions

Tags: arrays, regex, string, csv, split

I have a string: `strString = first,last,,4443334444`

I want to use regular expression to split this string into an array.

I'm using this regular expression `[\""].+?[\""]|[^,]+` but it is ignoring the space after the word last.

So, my array is looking something like this:

```
        [0] => first
        [1] => last
        [2] => 4443334444
```

instead of:

```
        [0] => first
        [1] => last
        [2] => 
        [3] => 4443334444
```

I would like to keep the space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Why not just use `string.split(',')`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Because it will split `"Text, text"` incorrectly. @TheGooose, try [`"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,]+|(?<=^|,)(?=$|,)`](https://regex101.com/r/oI6kY9/1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split a CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you for your response, it had the desired output and takes into account qualified text with quotes worked good for my use case.  I really appreciate all the responses and this awesome community.

Comment: I posted an answer. If you let know what language it is for, I could share a demo. Not sure you need it though :)

Comment: If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001150/3832970) worked for you, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,]+|(?<=^|,)(?=$|,)‌​
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI6kY9/1)

The expression consists of

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - a double quoted string literal with escape sequence support
- `|`  - or
- `[^,]+` - 1 or more characters other than `,`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=^|,)(?=$|,)‌​` - any empty string that is either between commas, or between the start/end of string and a comma.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with your expression.

1. First `[\""]` is redundant, use `["]` or better `"` (without the
   character class) instead.
2. Second, your actual problem is due to
   the `+` operator which requires at least **one** character (but
   there's none between the commas, thus disallowing empty fields).
3. Third, this is probably some `CSV` output, so why not use
   `explode()` or similar functions?

---

If you insist on using a regular expression, you might get along with:

```
".*?"|[^,]*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hU8hR7/2).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to get the element between the two commas, since there's no regex expression for it.  The best I could come up with is:

> str.match(/(?:[^,]+)|,,/g)
>
> => ["first", "last", ",,", "4443334444"]

But you'll need to translate the ",," into an empty string.

Is there a reason why you're using regex? Does your language have a .split() function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split