# How to parse null csv field in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

In my `javascript` code, I am parsing `csv` file and making `json` data later sending it to `mongodb` insert. During `csv` parsing i am facing some problem when any `csv` cell is empty or null. For example when data is

```
"abc", "xyz",,,"axbycz"
```

my expectation is `"abc", "xyz", null, null, "axbycz"` but i am getting only `"abc", "xyz", "axbycz"`.

Here is my actual data and regex to parse it.

Data:

```
263P,,,Madanayakanahalli,xys,abc,00:35 Min.,,
"[
  {
   "busstop": "MG Road", 
   "latlons": ["1.0455367265411", "17.5055545144687"]
   }
 ]",
 "08:35,  17:25","09:10,  18:00","07:55,  16:45","08:30, 15:35, 17:20"
```

Regex:

```
var cells = rows[i].match(/("\[.*?\]"|".*?"|".*?"\r|[^",]+)(?=,|$)/g);
```

This regex is working well if all cells have some data.

Please  someone help me to get the csv parsing as per my expectation.

Comment: If i answer your query using loop statement instead of regex, will that be fine???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)

Comment: i used regex because i have to parse huge data. I case of loop it may be time taking. But no issue, please suggest me the solution.