# how to skip a bad row in ssis flat file source

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am reading in a 17-column CSV file into a database.
once in a while the file has a "less then 17-column" row.
I am trying to ignore the row, but even when all columns are set to ignore, I can't ignore that row and the package fails.

How to ignore those rows?

Comment: What error causes the package to fail?  Is it failing while reading the file or writing to the database?

Comment: it's failing to read the file.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: cannot find delimiter on "phone type" which represents a record that did not have all of the requisite information.  the column "Phone Type" is column 15  of 17 in the list of fields, and in several records it's not there.  The file has over 400,000 to several million records in a given file.

Comment: Gotcha, I would use a StreamReader with a Try..catch block to throw out the bad rows.  This will avoid loading the entire file into memory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution Overview

you can do this by adding one `Flat File Connection Manager` add only one column with Data type `DT_WSTR` and a length of `4000` *(assuming it's name is `Column0`) - So all column are considered as one big column*

- In the `Dataflow task` add a `Script Component` after the `Flat File Source`
- In mark `Column0` as Input Column and Add 17 Output Columns
- In the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method split `Column0` by delimiter, Then check if the length of array is = 17 then assign values to output columns, Else ignore the row.

## Detailed Solution

1. Add a Flat file connection manager, Select the text file
2. Go to the **Advanced Tab**, Delete all Columns except one Column
3. Change the datatype of the remianing Column to `DT_WSTR` and length = `4000`

[image]

4. Add a DataFlow Task
5. Inside the Data Flow Task add a Flat File Source, Script Component and OLEDB Destination

[image]

6. In the Script Component Select `Column0` as Input Column

[image]

7. Add 17 Output Columns (the optimal output columns)
8. Change the `OutputBuffer` `SynchronousInput` property to `None`

[image]

9. Select the Script Language to `Visual Basic`

[image]

10. In the Script Editor write the following Script

    ```
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then


            Dim strColumns As String() = Row.Column0.Split(CChar(";"))

            If strColumns.Length <> 17 Then Exit Sub


            Output0Buffer.AddRow()
            Output0Buffer.Column = strColumns(0)
            Output0Buffer.Column1 = strColumns(1)
            Output0Buffer.Column2 = strColumns(2)
            Output0Buffer.Column3 = strColumns(3)
            Output0Buffer.Column4 = strColumns(4)
            Output0Buffer.Column5 = strColumns(5)
            Output0Buffer.Column6 = strColumns(6)
            Output0Buffer.Column7 = strColumns(7)
            Output0Buffer.Column8 = strColumns(8)
            Output0Buffer.Column9 = strColumns(9)
            Output0Buffer.Column10 = strColumns(10)
            Output0Buffer.Column11 = strColumns(11)
            Output0Buffer.Column12 = strColumns(12)
            Output0Buffer.Column13 = strColumns(13)
            Output0Buffer.Column14 = strColumns(14)
            Output0Buffer.Column15 = strColumns(15)
            Output0Buffer.Column16 = strColumns(16)

        End If

    End Sub
    ```
11. Map the Output Columns to the Destination Columns

Comment: It is no necessary. You can use `DT_STR`

Answer (score 2):

C# Solution for Loading CSV and skip rows that don't have 17 columns:

Use a Script Component:
On input/output screen add all of your outputs with data types.

```
string fName = @"C:\test.csv" // Full file path: it should reference via variable

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fName);

//add a counter
int ctr = 1;

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string[] cols = line.Split(',');

    if(ctr!=1) //Assumes Header row. elim if 1st row has data
    {
    if(cols.Length == 17)
    {
          //Write out to Output
          Output0Buffer.AddRow();
          Output0Buffer.Col1 = cols[0].ToString(); //You need to cast to data type
          Output0Buffer.Col2 = int.Parse(cols[1]) // example to cast to int
          Output0Buffer.Col3 = DateTime.Parse(cols[2]) // example of datetime
          ... //rest of Columns
    }
    //optional else to handle skipped lines
    //else 
    // write out line somewhere
    }
    ctr++; //increment counter
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith....this is awesome code.   can you tweak it for extremely LARGE files?  > 1Gb?  Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I would change if it were possible would be to change the split to Regex i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv in order to handle the issues that arise inside strings like quotes in quotes and commas in quotes

Comment: Instead of FileReadAllLines you can use a stream and ReadLine

Comment: Can this be accomplished with multiple files in a given file path?

Comment: @SidC - I added a separate answer on how to work with multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

This is for @SidC comment in my other answer.

This lets you work with multiple files:

```
        //set up variables
        string line;
        int ctr = 0;

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:/path", "filenames*.txt");
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            var str = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
            while((line = str.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Work with line here similar to the other answer
            }
        }
```