# Regex Split with Quotes and Commas

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split the following strings by `comma` but the name field with the `quotations` is causing a problem. What would be the best Regex pattern to handle this use case?

Below is a sample of the text.

```
7,"U.S. Representative, Dist I - N",7,"OF",,367,20,"GRIFFIN, Calvin (G)",1,"",314,45,193,552
8,"U.S. Representative, Dist I - D",8,"OF",,3991,24,"HANABUSA, Colleen Wakako",2,"",43493,4472,26057,74022
8,"U.S. Representative, Dist I - D",8,"OF",,3991,22,"AHU ISA, Lei (Leinaala)",1,"",6690,741,4087,11518
```

Comment: Don't roll your own CSV parser.  Use an already established library, they have solved all the issues you will encounter already

Comment: @maccettura i agree with your answer.  You might want to link a few good csv parsers so that your answer becomes a full solution.

Comment: @Juls It is not an answer to question, hence a comment. Very good advice, though. For the CSV libs: I think I remember that there was a website, where you can enter some words and it has a database with possible websites that match ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments that refer that you should go with a csv parser solution but if you really intend to use regex here is a good start point:

```
"[^"\r\n]*"|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yFvfhF/1).

Comment: Rui,  works for PHP but getting an error with C#.

Comment: Here is my c# code. Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^"\r\n]* "|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*");

Comment: See [this](http://rextester.com/AQYI10716) :)

Comment: Bingo...:)  Thanks Rui

Comment: You're welcome :) please vote :)