# Django v2+ regex for custom path converter to handle csv

Tags: django, django-urls

Note: prior to posting I already searched for csv regex. The best regex I found for csv so far can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806378/5623899).

---

I would like to create a custom path converter for handling a csv e.g. something like:

```
register_converter(CSVConverter, 'csv')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('csv/<csv:list_of_values>/', views.csv_view, name='csv_view'),
    ...
]
```

where each value of `list_of_values` is a string that does *not* need to be wrapped in quotes e.g.

```
http://localhost:8000/csv/value1,value2,value3/
```

I tried the following:

```
class CSVConverter:
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806378/5623899
    regex = "(?:,|\n|^)(\"(?:(?:\"\")*[^\"]*)*\"|[^\",\n]*|(?:\n|$))"

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split(',')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(value)
```

but this doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't need a complicated regular expression. You simply have to capture any string not containing a slash (`/`), the splitting up is handled by `to_python()`. You can simply use the regex from the built-in [`StringConverter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/urls/converters/):

```
class CSVConverter:
    regex = '[^/]+'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split(',')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(value)
```

Alternatively, you can also subclass `StringConverter`:

```
from django.urls.converters import StringConverter

class CSVConverter(StringConverter):

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split(',')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(value)
```

Comment: True, definitely was over thinking that one!