# Having multiple double quotes inside quoted string csv file

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, str-replace, double-quotes

I am having a csv file, quotes around each field.

there are some fields, which can have multiple double quotes inside them. I want to escape each of them with additional double quote.

> ","ABC "XYZ" PQRS","
> ","ABC "XYZ"","
> ","ABC "A" "B" TEST","
> ","ABC 2.5" "C" Test","

I took help from the [link](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/10394/select-string-string-replace) and able to cover for scenarios with single double quote inside content, using regular expression `[regex]$r='(","[^"]+"[^"]+?",")'`. But, stuck up in the cases, where there are multiple double quotes inside content.

```
[regex]$r='(","[^"]+"[^"]+"",")' # Not working
get-content C:\Projects\MyProject\testRegexFordoublequotes.csv | foreach {

  #save each line to a variable to make it easier to track

  $line=$_

  #look for a regex match

  $find=$r.matches($line)
  
  if ($find[0].Success) { 

      foreach ($match in $find) {

        #the original string we matched on

        $found=$match.value

        #replace the substring

        $replace= '","'+  $found.Trim('","').Replace('""','"').Replace('"','""')+ '","'

        #replace the full string and write to the pipeline

        $line -replace $found,$replace

      } #foreach
       

  } #if

  else {

        #no match so write the line to pipeline

        $line

    }

 } | Set-Content C:\Projects\MyProject\modified.csv -Force
```

Can you please help me in defining regex which will be helpful for multiple double quotes inside field.

Comment: Use something like `Import-Csv` instead of trying to parse it out yourself.

Comment: @MattClark, thanks for your suggestion. Importing is failing, due to double quotes inside content for some fields. Also, there are ~250k files like this, and there are many fields like this. So, wanted to do it using regex to do it faster

Comment: [Have fun with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147076/1790644).

Comment: @MattClark, I am not very good in regex. Looks very complicated to implement. As you are suggestion, let me see, if I can handle it using csv parser. but, I need to figure out the files with these types of content

Comment: As others pointed out, it is better to use a CSV parser such as https://github.com/peterthoeny/parse-csv-js. However, your text does not conform to CSV, so a CSV parser would not help. Are these actual lines or shortened lines? A `","` at the beginning and end look strange. Also, are all fields enclosed in quotes, e.g. are adjacent fields always separated by `","`?

Comment: @PeterThoeny, I am just putting  part of the text which I want to match. We are having csv with quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easier to search for the *valid* delimiters (e.g. `"\s*,\s*"`) and split your lines into fields, and than simply correct each (invalid) single double quote with 2 quotes in each field.
Than rebuild the fields to a record by surrounding the fields with double quotes and join them with the `csv` (comma) delimiter

**Input**

```
$Csv = @'
"Field","ABC "XYZ" PQRS","Field"
"Field","ABC "XYZ"","Field"
"Field","ABC "A" "B" TEST","Field"
"Field","ABC 2.5" "C" Test","Field"
'@ -Split '[\r\n]+'
```

**Script**

```
$Csv | # replace with: get-content .\testRegexFordoublequotes.csv |
Foreach-Object {
    $Line = $_ -Replace '^\s*"' -Replace '"\s*$' # Strip outer double quotes
    $Fields = $Line -Split '"\s*,\s*"'           # Split line into fields
    $Fields = $Fields -Replace '"', '""'         # Escape each " in each field
    '"' + ($Fields -Join '","') + '"'            # Rejoin the fields to line
} # append: | Set-Content .\modified.csv -Force
```

**Output**

```
"Field","ABC ""XYZ"" PQRS","Field"
"Field","ABC ""XYZ""","Field"
"Field","ABC ""A"" ""B"" TEST","Field"
"Field","ABC 2.5"" ""C"" Test","Field"
```

Comment: FYI, I just simplified the script in the answer a bit as you actually don't need to iterate through each field if you use the PowerShell [`-Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operator: [*When the `<input>` to the -replace operator is a collection, PowerShell applies the replacement to every value in the collection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the conversation we had in the comments of the post, the files are non-conformant CSV files, hence a CSV parser is of no help.

Mind you, you have an undefined case if a single cell happens to have a `some textext","more text`. That cell will be treated as two cells because of the unescaped quotes.

Now to the regex. You could find a regex with lookahead and lookbehind, but I think it is easier to blindly double all quotes, then cleanup the unintended ones, e.g. at the start & end of line, and in between cells.

I am not familiar with powershell, but here is a JavaScript/pseudo code that you can easily convert to the powershell syntax. I am using a single line containing all your stated test cases; you would loop through the lines in your file:

```
/* assume $line is:
"Start","ABC "XYZ" PQRS","ABC "XYZ"","ABC "A" "B" TEST","ABC 2.5" "C" Test","End"
*/

$fixed = $line.replace(/"/g, '""')
              .replace(/"",""/g, '","')
              .replace(/^""/, '"')
              .replace(/""$/, '"')

/* $fixed is:
"Start","ABC ""XYZ"" PQRS","ABC ""XYZ""","ABC ""A"" ""B"" TEST","ABC 2.5"" ""C"" Test","End"
*/
```

Explanation:

- `.replace(/"/g, '""')` - blindly double all quotes
- `.replace(/"",""/g, '","')` - restore `"",""` back to `","`
- `.replace(/^""/, '"')` - restore `""` at start of line to `"`
- `.replace(/""$/, '"')` - restore `""` at end of line to `"`

Comment: thanks. different approach to solve the problem. very useful. I chose the other one, considering it was useful for somebody to refer to in future in the power shell syntax. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may do the following to see what the changes will be:

```
(Get-Content file.csv) -replace '(?<!^|",)"(?!,"|$)','""'
```

You can simply pipe to `Set-Content` to save the new contents:

```
(Get-Content file.csv) -replace '(?<!^|",)"(?!,"|$)','""' |
    Set-Content file.csv
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<!^|",)` is a negative lookbehind look for any previous position that is not the beginning of a line (`^`) or `",`. `(?!,"|$)` is a negative lookahead for any next position that is not the end of a line (`$`) or `,"`. If those look around conditions are met, the `"` is replaced with `""`.