# Regex to match multiple sub groups?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Given the following string:

```
text,text,text,text
text,"text,text",text,text
text,text,text,text
text,"text,text",text,"text,text"
```

How can I match only the commas between quotes?

[image]

Context: I'm trying to "clean" this data from a CSV file so I can properly split the lines with `.split(",")` in JS.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It's good that you also state the original purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using an NPM package like [`csv-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) which should handle all edge cases of your CSV file. However, if this is not an option, you can use this regular expression which can parse your example input but **does not** handle all use cases, such as escaped quotes:

```
(?<=^|,)("([^"]*)"|[^,]*)(?=,|$)
```

##### Explanation:

- `(?<=^|,)`: Previous character should be a comma or the beginning of the line
- `("([^"]*)"|[^,]*)`: Capturing group 1 should either be:

  - `"([^"]*)"`: Surrounded by double quotes and no `"` within the string

    - `([^"]*)`: Capture group 2 only captures the string within `""`
  - `[^,]*`: Not surrounded by double quotes and no `,` within the string
- `(?=,|$)`: The next character should be a comma or the end of the line

##### Example implementation:

```js
function simpleCSVParser(csv) {
    const re = /(?<=^|,)("([^"]*)"|[^,]*)(?=,|$)/g,
        matches = csv.split('\n').map(csvLine => csvLine.matchAll(re)),
        csvData = [];
    for (let matchLine of matches) {
        csvData.push([]);
        for (let match of matchLine) {
            // Push match group 2 (double quoted string with quotes removed) to
            // the last line of the CSV if it exists, otherwise push match group 1
            csvData[csvData.length - 1].push(match[2] ?? match[1]);
        }
    }
    return csvData;
}
```

With your input of:

```
text,text,text,text
text,"text,text",text,text
text,text,text,text
text,"text,text",text,"text,text"
```

The output of the function is:

```json
[
  ["text", "text", "text", "text"],
  ["text", "text,text", "text", "text"],
  ["text", "text", "text", "text"],
  ["text", "text,text", "text", "text,text"]
]
```

##### Other Solutions:

If you want a regular expression to handle more edge cases, I recommend taking a look at this question: [Regex to split a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)